# PHP contact form not validating or sending

Tags: php, html, email-validation, contact-form

Ok...so I grabbed this PHP contact form from a combination of a few different websites and from a predecessor. I've been wrestling with it for hours and can't figure it out.

**In all fairness, know that PHP is not my strong suit, at all**, (I'm a client-side programmer). Here's the code below, please help if you can. Thank you!

**Here are some of the error messages I've seen:**

The most recent:
*Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF in /home/[...] on line 11*

Before, here was the error message, but I believe I fixed the "blank field" part:

*It appears that you left a blank field.*

*Please make sure you fill in your full name, email address, subject, and details.
Click the back arrow to return to the contact form.*

*From:... List:; syntax illegal for recipient addresses*

*Reply-To:... List:; syntax illegal for recipient addresses*

*X-Mailer:... List:; syntax illegal for recipient addresses*

*Thank you, [name], for contacting us!*

**Here's the HTML**

```
<form action="contactus.php" method="post" class="create">
     <fieldset>
    <legend align="center">Please fill out details below and click "Submit"</legend>
    <div>
     <label for="fullname" class="fixedwidth">Full Name</label>
     <input type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname" class="input2"/>
    </div><br/>
    <div>
     <label for="email" class="fixedwidth">Email</label>
     <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="input2"/>
    </div><br/>
      <div>
     <label for="subject" class="fixedwidth">Subject</label>
     <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" class="input2"/>
    </div><br/>
    <div>
    <label for="details" class="fixedwidth">Body</label>
     <textarea id="details" name="details" cols="62" rows="20"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="buttonarea">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </div>

    </fieldset>
   </form>
```

**...and here's the contactus.php file:**

```
<?php

 $fullname = $_POST['fullname'];
 $subject = $_POST['subject'];
 $details = $_POST['details'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];

//*** Function to check email address */
 function checkemail($email) { 
  $regex = '/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/'
   if (eregi($regex ,$email))
   { 
    return true; 
   } 
    else
   { 
    return false; 
   } 
 }

//*** Check to see if the email address is valid */
 else if (checkemail($email) == false) { 
  echo "<br/><br/><p><center>It appears that you have entered an invalid email address.<br/> Please check your email again.</p>";
 }

//*** Mail Processing */
 if ($_POST['submit']) {
 //Check for blank fields
  if ($fullname !== "" && $email !== "" && $subject !== "" && $details !== "") {
   echo "<br/><br/><p><center>It appears that you left a blank field.<br/> 
   Please make sure you fill in your full name, email address, subject, and details.<br/>
   Click the back arrow to return to the contact form.</p>";
  }

//*** Send Mail**/
 $to = 'sgraffito22@gmail.com';
 $fullname = $_POST['fullname'];
 $subject = $_POST['subject'];
 $details = $_POST['details'];

 $headers = 'From: '.$email."\r\n".
 'Reply-To: '.$email."\r\n" .
 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

 mail($to, $fullname, $subject, $details, $headers);
 echo "<br><br><p><center>Thank you, $fullname, for contacting us!</p><br><br>";

}

?>
```

Comment: Couple of tips: 1. indent your code properly, that way folks will be more inclined to read it, 2. If there are, add any error messages you are seeing to the question as well. 3. Strip the code example back to the bare minimum - at the moment it's cluttered with debug `echo` statements which make the snippet hard to read. 4. Did you check to make sure you have basic mail sending functionality on the server by running a simple `mail()` script?

Comment: thanks @Kev I'll work on the indenting part right now as well as posting the error messages...I know the server has basic sending functionality...updates soon, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `;` at the end of

```
$regex = '/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/'
```

Your `From`, `Reply-to`, and `X-Mailer` syntax errors could be caused by switching between `'` and `"` in `$headers`

```
$headers = 'From: '.$email."\r\n".
  'Reply-To: '.$email."\r\n" .
   'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```

try changing to -

```
$headers  = "From: ".$email."\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ".$email."\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since regex solution has been given by Sean,

Here is my previous project regex I used,

```
$regex= "/^[\.a-z0-9_\-]+[@][a-z0-9_\-]+([.][a-z0-9_\-]+)+[a-z]{1,4}$/i";
```

This is another alternative for PHP mailing, you will need to download phpmailer plugin in order for this mailing to work.

```
<?php
// mail config start 

$emailAddress = 'youremailhere';
$replyAdress ='yourreceipientemailhere';
$replyName = 'yourreceipientname';
$msgSubject= 'yoursubjecthere';


// mail config end 

// Include the class,
require "phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php";

//Type your message here:
$msg = 'blablayourmessagehere';

//The mailing process begins!!
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsMail();

$mail->AddReplyTo($replyAdress, $replyName);
$mail->AddAddress($emailAddress);
$mail->SetFrom($replyAdress, $replyName);
$mail->Subject = "New: ".$replyName." have sent a ".$msgSubject." message";

$mail->MsgHTML($msg);

$mail->Send();

?>
```

Comment: You can replace those variables with the submission details.