# Simple PHP Contact Form Not Sending

Tags: php, email, contacts, contact-form

After posting a more [robust example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12169912/php-contact-form-not-validating-or-sending) I couldn't figure out, and browsing around on a few entries with no avail, I can't get possibly the simplest PHP contact form in the world to work.

I broke it down from the last entry to see if I could at least  *send* an email. I've tested all the $var elements and they're being recognized with a simple echo check, so I know that's not the issue. I also checked the SMTP compatibility and that's fine too.

The probelm is when I click "Submit" on the live form, the message will pop up saying "Thank You" but I'm not receiving any emails in my inbox.

What could I be missing here?

**To start, here's the HTML**

```
    <form action="contactus.php" method="POST" class="create">
     <fieldset>
    <legend align="center">Please fill out details below and click "Submit"</legend>
    <div>
     <label for="fullname" class="fixedwidth">Full Name</label>
     <input type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname" class="input2"/>
    </div><br/>
    <div>
     <label for="email" class="fixedwidth">Email</label>
     <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="input2"/>
    </div><br/>
      <div>
     <label for="subject" class="fixedwidth">Subject</label>
     <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" class="input2"/>
    </div><br/>
    <div>
    <label for="details" class="fixedwidth">Body</label>
     <textarea id="details" name="details" cols="62" rows="20"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="buttonarea">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </div>

    </fieldset>
   </form>
```

**and here's the PHP**

```
<?php 
$fullname = $_POST['fullname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$details = $_POST['details'];
$formcontent = "From: $fullname \n Message: $details";
$recipient = "johndoe1@email.com";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You!";
?>
```

Comment: Assuming that `mail()` isn't returning an error, the next place to check would be your mail logs.

Comment: Have you actually checked the return value of `mail()`?

Comment: Have you checked your spam inbox?

Comment: @SebastiánGrignoli I can't believe I fell for that. Right on man, you got it.

Comment: validate $_POST['email']. and check again.
Check the link below. its a working php email submit.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12214875/php-email-submit/12215023#12215023

Comment: you may find this link helpful: http://phpfragments.com/php-contact-form/